# Why “相同意思的词” is called “同义词” instead of “同意词”？

Tags: abbreviations

Why is the abbreviation of “相同意思的词” “同义词” instead of “同意词”？

Comment: [百度百科](http://baike.baidu.com/view/17171020.htm)上说两者是可以互换的

Comment: @賈可Jacky, on the same page it also says "爸爸"与"父亲"，分别是旧词与新词. Do you agree?

Comment: I don't think 爸爸 and 父亲 are interchangable in all cases, it does not like that **dad** and **father** in English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

同义词 = 相**同** 定**义**(definition) 的**词**

aka words with same definition.

As for why 同意词 isn't used, I cannot find any authoritative source, however I believe it's mainly to avoid conflict with the word 同意 (v. agree, n. agreement).